# Issue with displaying quantity button in proper position in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a page using Python, it has 2 frames, one frame is to display the products and when we click upon the product it should perform a mouseclickevent and should display in second frame. Along with the product name it should display quantity with + and - option to increment and decrement.

I am using pycharm professional 2017.3.2

This is my code:

```
def OnDoubleClick(event):
    a = tree.selection()[0]
    price = tree.item(a, "values")
    amt = price[1]
    print("amt is :",amt)

    t1=0

    v1 = IntVar(receiptbox, value='1')

    def onMinus():
        if (v1.get()>0):
            v1.set(v1.get() - 1)

    btn1 = Button(receiptbox, justify=CENTER, text="-
",command=onMinus,bg="#33ccff")
    receiptbox.insert(END, "\n")
    btn1.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=E)


    e1 = Entry(receiptbox, justify=CENTER, textvariable=v1, width=4, state="readonly")
    e1.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=E)

    def onPlus():
        v1.set(v1.get() + 1)
# receiptbox.delete("1.0", END)
        if(v1.get()>1):
            receiptbox.delete("1.0", END)
# v1.set(v1.get() + 1)
            var = v1.get()
            price = tree.item(a, "values")
            amt1 = (price[1])
# amt2 = int(amt1)

# t1 = float(amt1) * (var)
            receiptbox.insert(END, tree.item(a, "text") + " Sub Total: "+str(float(amt1) * (var)))
            receiptbox.insert(END,"\n")


    btn2 = Button(receiptbox, justify=CENTER, text="+", command=onPlus,bg="#33ccff")
    btn2.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=E)

    receiptbox.insert(END,"\n")

    if (v1.get()==1):
        total = (v1.get() * amt)
        print("Total is :"+str(total))
        receiptbox.insert(END, tree.item(a, "text") + " Sub Total: " + str(total))
        receiptbox.insert(END, "\n")
        receiptbox.insert(END, "\n\n")
```

I am able to display the list of product  and mouseclick is working fine. Products are listed from the database. The issue is with the quantity button. Its not coming in the proper position. I mean it should display in the same row along with the product name.

Comment: please fix indentation

Comment: fixed indentation